# Abrir variables de sesion y cerrar en PHP 5.6

Tags: php, php5

Quiero crear una sesion para que no se pueda acceder al index sin antes pasar por el login.php pero no logro hacer que funcione, intente crear variables de sesion pero al parecer no funciona, funciona que solo con las credenciales correctas pasas el login pero si modificas la url a index.php te deja pasar sin ir por el login... como seria esto?
mi form:

```
                <form action="log.php" form method="POST" id="action"> 

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control input_user"  placeholder="Usuario" required="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control input_pass"  placeholder="Password" required="">
                    </div>
                    <br>


            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Entrar" >Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

mi log.php

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$username = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['username']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password  = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//$tsql="";
//$msg="";
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
echo $_SESSION['username'];

    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

if($stmt){
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
    if($rows === true){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');

    die();
}else{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}

    }
```

y segun tambien coloque un boton de [SALIR] para cerrar la sesion que así tengo el php

```
<?php 
session_start();
unset ($SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();

header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

Comment: lo llegaste a resolver? que me tuve que ir

Comment: Si bro, ya, gracias, colocare tu respuesta como la que me ayudo, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a parte de comprobar que las credenciales al entrar en la aplicación, después debes comprobar en todas y cada una de las paginas que la sesion se inicio para poder navegar, como por ejemplo

Este archivo se llama comprobariniciosesion.php

```html
<?php

//Arrancamos la sesión
session_start();
//Comprobamos existencia de sesión
if (!isset($_SESSION['Usuario']) && !isset($_SESSION['Contrasena'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

en cada uno de los archivos hago

```html
require('comprobariniciosesion.php');
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94655/discussion-on-answer-by-ketemeto-abrir-variables-de-sesion-y-cerrar-en-php-5-6).